# Can i embed anychart in my gMail

Tags: anychart

Am using Pie chart in AnyChart and is it possible to put the Pie chart in an email and send it across? The requirement is like i need to mail a report to my superiors and in the mail body, would it be possible to place the pie chart?

Comment: Do you use AnyChart 6 (Flash) or AnyChart 7 (HTML 5)?

Comment: Using AnyChart 7 with HTML5

Comment: There is no solution from AnyChart on this???

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send chart in the email you need to save a chart as image:
http://docs.anychart.com/latest/Common_Settings/Exports
This can be done either by client-side script or generated on the server side and sent, take a look at Server Side Chart Rendering documents for more information:
http://docs.anychart.com/latest/Common_Settings/Server-side_Rendering